# Get online users and offline users in a single query instead of two seperate queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named users which has two columns, id and last_activity,

Currently I'm doing like this to get all users who are online

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_activity + 300 > NOW();
```

And doing this to get offline users

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_activity + 300 < NOW();
```

And then combine the results to display them on a page with specific icon (either green or red) depending on the status.

How can I add a column in the fly say for example (is_online) this column should be associated with each row, so I can get something like the following. So I can combine both queries above in a single query and be able to distinguish the status of the user later?

```
id    | is_online
1337  | 1
1334  | 1
XXXX  | 0
```

The column is_online doesn't actually exist in the table, I want to create it on the fly and give it the value 1 if last_activity+300>NOW() otherwise give it the value 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the single query to get the required result along with the additional column which you want using CASE like this

```
SELECT  Id, 
        CASE
          WHEN last_activity + 300 > NOW() THEN 1
          ELSE 0 
        END as Is_Online
FROM Users
```

Answer (score 4):

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers.  You can just do:

```
SELECT u.*, (last_activity + 300 > NOW()) as is_online
FROM users u;
```